# Redirect to new domain and preserve username

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I recently switched to a new domain for a version control server I run.  The server is usually accessed with a username included in the url such as `https://userinfo@sub.olddomain.com/some/stuff`.  I want to redirect requests to the old domain to the new domain and preserve everything else in the url (including the username). So the former url would be redirected to `https://userinfo@sub.newdomain.net/some/stuff`. Currently I have the following rewrite condition and rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} sub\.olddomain\.com 
RewriteRule (.*) https://sub.newdomain.net$1 [R=301,L]
```

This works except it drops the `userinfo` part of the URL.  Is there a way I can preserve the user info?

Comment: You might try some condition using %{REMOTE_USER}

Answer (score 2):

From the perspective of the server user info isn't part of the URL. When you request a URL with a user name your browser will set an authorization header. The user name is available to rewriterules however, in the `%{REMOTE_USER}` variable.

So you could try something like:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} sub\.olddomain\.com 
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{REMOTE_USER}@sub.newdomain.net$1 [R=301,L]
```

The user will have to authenticate again on the new server however. There's no way around that.